# Perpendicularity is not transitive

Tags: geometry, vector-spaces, metric-spaces, euclidean-geometry

How to convince someone that if a plane (Pxy,P,Pz) is perpendicular to a plane (O,Px,Py) and the plane (Px,O,Py) is perpendicular to the plane (Px,Pxz,Pz) is not always true that (Pz,P,Pxy) is perpendicular to (Pz,Pxz,Px)?

Observations: P is a vector, O is the origin, and the other are the projections on the planes xy, xz, yz

Comment: This is hard to read.  But if $\mathscr P_1$ is perpendicular to $\mathscr P_2$ then $\mathscr P_2$ is perpendicular to $\mathscr P_1$ but $\mathscr P_1$ isn't perpendicular to itself.

Comment: Draw the planes with GeoGebra.

Comment: Is for example $Pxy$ the projection on plane $Oxy$ and $Px$ the projection on **axis** $Ox$ ?

Comment: No answer to my question ?

Comment: @JeanMarie yes, they are